# wrong size and positon of UITextView after creating Box for its contours

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring

I was trying wrap test into enclosing box by means of boundingrectwithsize function.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if let messageText = messages?[indexPath.item].text {
        let size = CGSize(width:view.frame.width,height: 1000)
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin.union(.usesFontLeading)
        let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: messageText).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width,height: estimatedFrame.height)
    }

    return CGSize(width:view.frame.width,height: 100)
}
```

}

But the output was something weird and  i am very confused

[image]

why it did always cutting last string? It seemed to me i was using right NSString.DrawingOptions and especially usesFontLeading calculates the size but why it cut the last string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITextView` adds padding by default. Sizing using `NSString` sizing methods don't take this into account. You can either turn off the padding using:

```
myTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
myTextView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
```

Or add them to your size:

```
CGSize(width: view.frame.width,height: estimatedFrame.height + myTextView.textContainerInset.top + myTextView.textContainerInset.bottom)
```